# Doubts regarding Dedekind construction of R starting from Q (Rudin PMA)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I followed the 9 steps  given by Rudin but in the end I didn't fully understand. My main questions are the following (in my understanding 2. is the follow up of 1.):

1. since the members of R have been defined as *cuts* of Q (thus containing rational numbers), how does this definition of R let appear the irrational numbers in R in the end?
2. In step 9 (the end indeed!) Rudin writes:

> *It is this identification of Q with Q' which allows us to regard Q as a subfield of R*

What's the link between Q->Q'->R? Is Q' actually R? I understand that Q' contains cuts and it is isomorphic to Q. R also contains cuts by definition but how is it that Q is a subfield of R?

I hope my doubts are clear and I thank you in advance!

p.s.

Q' is what Rudin writes for Q* but in the post the star symbol gave me trouble forcing italics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C=\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<0\}\cup\{q\in\Bbb Q:q^2<2\}$; then the cut $C$ is the irrational number $\sqrt2$: it appears in the right place in the linear order on $\Bbb R$, and its square, using the definition of multiplication in $\Bbb R$, is $\{q\in\Bbb Q:q<2\}$, i.e., the member of $\Bbb Q'$ corresponding to $2\in\Bbb Q$. The other irrational numbers also appear as cuts: there is one for each cut $C$ with the property that $\Bbb Q\setminus C$ does not have a smallest element.

For your second question, the assertion is not that $\Bbb Q$ is literally a subfield of $\Bbb R$; after all, it is not even a sub**set** of $\Bbb R$, so it can hardly be a sub**field**. However, $\Bbb Q'$ **is** a subfield of $\Bbb R$, and $\Bbb Q$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q'$, so from a purely algebraic and order-theoretic point of view $\Bbb Q'$ is indistinguishable from $\Bbb Q$. Thus, for all practical purposes we can think of $\Bbb Q'$ as actually being $\Bbb Q$, as if $\Bbb Q$ itself were a subset (and subfield) of $\Bbb R$, even though in this construction of $\Bbb R$ that is not literally the case.

Comment: @erma: No, I mean that in this construction of $\Bbb R$ the cut $C$ **is** $\sqrt2$. Until we construct $\Bbb R$, there is no $\sqrt2$: we have only the rational numbers. We’re building a structure in which $2$ does have a square root. There are actually several different ways to construct $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$; the construction by Dedekind cuts is only one of them. Each of these constructions produces a different $\Bbb R$: with this one $\Bbb R$ is a collection of sets of rationals, and with the other most common one $\Bbb R$ is a collection of sets of Cauchy sequences of rationals. The ...

Comment: ... important thing is that the objects that they produce are all isomorphic: for all algebraic and order-theoretic purposes they can be treated as the same object — the same linear order, the same field, and so on. Both of these are constructed from $\Bbb Q$, and neither literally contains that $\Bbb Q$ as a subset, but each of them contains an isomorphic copy of that $\Bbb Q$. In the Dedekind construction, $\sqrt2$ **is** a set of rationals. So is the member of $\Bbb Q'$ that we identify with $2\in\Bbb Q$. (And yes, throughout my answer $\Bbb R$ denotes the set of Dedekind cuts in $\Bbb Q$.)

Comment: Thanks @Brian for your exhaustive answer. I have some questions:\\ 1) When you say "..then the cut C is the irrational number sqrt(2).." do you mean "is associated to the irrational number"? I guess my question is: how sqrt(2) even exists in R if R contains cuts of rationals?\\ 2) Why "Q is not even a subset of R"? Do you mean it with these definitions of Q and R?

Comment: @erma: I already tried to answer those questions in the double comment above; I really don’t know what more I can say.

Comment: It's all clear indeed. I accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @erma: You’re welcome!